# Remove blue highlight in <select > option tag

Tags: html, css, border

is there a way to remove the blue highlight in the select option tag?
I have tried it with:

```css
select {
outline: none;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

It is important because, each option tag has a different background color.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use :focus declaration. In this case:

```
input:focus {outline:none;}
```

All the input's in your project won't have the blue border.

If you want a specific attribute, use this:

```
input[type=text]:focus {outline:none;}
```

Hope it helps. =)

Comment: Yeah i had tried also with : focus  and :hover but nothing seams to work thanks anyway